# How do I deploy a Shout IRC client to OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, irc

I wanted to have an IRC bouncer for free, but I didn't trust the many free IRC bouncer services available out there. After some search, I discovered [Shout](http://shout-irc.com/), a Node.js IRC client for the browser. Shout has some really interesting features; among them, there were two I was particularly interested in:

- **Always connected**. I could be online 24/7.
- **Cross platform**. I could connect to my IRC client using any platform where a web browser is available.

On top of that, it looks pretty nifty and it's themeable via CSS.

Now I needed some kind of service that kept my Shout instance running 24/7 and allowed me to connect to it. Oh, and I wanted this for free.

This is where [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) comes into play. Their free account should be enough for this. Also, since they provide SSL, it should be possible to connect to Shout securely. The question then is: How do I deploy my Shout instance to OpenShift? (AKA, how do I get a secure, always-online IRC bouncer for free?)

Comment: FYI, Shout is now inactive and has been replaced by its official community-run fork: The Lounge (https://thelounge.github.io).

Comment: Also, the process described here should be the exact same one, and you can find additional info at https://github.com/pacbard/openshift-thelounge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *[Create an OpenShift Free
   account](https://www.openshift.com/app/account/new)*. The most basic
   account should suffice for our purposes.
2. *Log in to your OpenShift account*.
3. *Create a new Node.js application*.

   1. Go to the "Add Application" button in the "Applications" tab in
      OpenShift's console.
   2. Choose the Node.js cartridge from "Other types".
   3. Fill in appropriate fields, including the Public URL field. This
      URL will be the one you'll have to point your browser to when you
      wanted to connect to Shout.
4. Go to the "Applications" tab, and select your newly created
   application.
5. *Copy the URL under the "Source Code" title*. This is the URL you'll
   clone from. OpenShift is based on Git.
6. *Go to a terminal and run `git clone <URL>`, where `<URL>` is the URL
   you just copied from the page*. This will clone an already cooked
   repository for your application.
7. *Get rid of all the files in that repository running `rm -rf .` while
   in the repository's directory*. While the files there are a good
   starting point for your own application, we're not going to use
   them, since all we need is in Shout's repository.
8. *Clone Shout's repository somewhere else in your filesystem, with `git
   clone https://github.com/erming/shout`*.
9. *From your application's directory, run `git pull <Shout's dir>`*.
   This should populate your application's repository with all the files
   in Shout's repository.
10. *Change the `package.json` file*. Make the `start` member under the
    `scripts` attribute look like this:

    ```
    "start": "node index --private --home $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/shout/ --host $OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP --port $OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT",
    ```
11. *Tell OpenShift it has to use `npm start` to run our application*.
    For this, while in your application's directory, run `mkdir -p
    .openshift/markers` and then run `touch .openshift/markers/use_npm`.
12. *Commit with all the changes, and then do a `git push origin
    master`*.

After deployment finishes, you should be able to go to your
application's Public URL and see Shout right there.

**Important:** If you want to be on the safe side, access your Public URL with *https* rather than *http*. Changing the protocol prefix should be enough for this to work, since [OpenShift provides an `*.rhcloud.com` wildcard certificate](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202535440-How-do-I-get-SSL-for-my-domains-) that allows you to connect securely using your application's OpenShift-provided hostname URL.